# ROS vs ROS 2.0 vs ROS industrial

Tags: ros, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi community,

From your knowledge, readings, researches ... what is the difference between ROS, ROS 2.0, industrial ros ?
and please share any related documentation.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/335207/ros-vs-ros-2.0-vs-ros-industrial/) by [Youssef_Lah](https://answers.ros.org/users/41510/youssef_lah/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2019-10-11

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a wide topic to be discussed here and similar questions regarding this already exists. You can check [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/247442/what-is-different-with-ros-industrial/) question for more information about comparing ROS and ROS industrial and [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/287470/what-is-the-difference-between-ros-and-ros2/) for  ROS and ROS2.
[Here](https://www.theconstructsim.com/infographic-ros-1-vs-ros-2-one-better-2/) you can also find a nice visual comparison and documentation links.

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2019-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jeremya](https://answers.ros.org/users/23980/jeremya/) on 2019-10-12**:
To add on to this, ROS-I is a consortium. The consortium promotes and uses standard ROS and ROS2 for use in industrial settings. It's often confused as another version of ROS.